# how to write R function to make values close to zero to zero and leaving others as is

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 columns and 40 rows. The 1st two columns contain a value range from -1 to 1, and the 3rd column contains the sum of the two columns. Therefore, I would like to change values closer to zero, such as 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3 in the 3rd columns to zero and the rest as it was.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(2)
D = data.frame(from = runif(40, -1,1), to = runif(40,-1,1)) %>% dplyr::mutate(weight = from + to)
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `replace`, check if the `abs`olute value is below a threshold:

```r
thrs = 0.5
transform(D, weight = replace(weight, abs(weight) < thrs, 0))
```

Or in the `dplyr` framework:

```r
D %>% 
  mutate(weight = replace(weight, abs(weight) < 0.5, 0))
```

Comment: Would you please be able to show me how to make values closer to zero to be closer to zero, not exactly zero? Simply I want to decrease the distance between zero and values closer to zero while keeping values far from zero the same.